# Regex solution to redirect url subpages from /blog/site/info to /news/site/info

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am currently looking at routing pages from

http://example.com/**blog**/article/information

to

http://example.com/**news**/article/information

I am using a plugin for umbraco cms (301 url tracker), that requires two values.

1.Regex

2.Redirect URL, this supposts backreferences.

Iattempted these values, but no luck

1. `^/blog/1`
2. `news/$1`

Thanks,

M

Comment: What is the URL part that the regex recieves? Try `^/blog/(.*)` and `/news/$1` or  `^blog/(.*)` and `news/$1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually use a **backreference** you need to declare a **capturing group** in the regex pattern first. A capturing group is defined with a pair of unescaped parentheses: `(...)` where `...` stand for the pattern to be captured.

So, you can use

- Regex: `^/blog/(.*)`
- Rewrite: `/news/$1`

Where `^/blog/(.*)` matches `/blog/` at the start of the input string, and then captures all after it into Group 1 with `.*` (any 0+ characters other than a newline), and replaces with `/news/` + the value inside Group 1.